# How to load fxml file inside Pane?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, fxml

[image]

If we have a `Stage` then `Scene` includes 2 `Pane`s
the 1st `Pane` contains `Button` and the 2nd `Pane` is empty
could we load other fxml file inside this 2nd `Pane`?

```
fxml1: VBox
               |_Pane1-->Button
               |_Pane2
///////////////
fxml2: Pane--> Welcome to fxml 2
"when we click the button load the fxml2 inside Pane2 of fxml1"
```

Then after click

[image]

---

====I finally found this works after trying !====Thank you guys

```
@FXML Pane secPane;
public void loadFxml (ActionEvent event) {
Pane newLoadedPane =        FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/application/fxml2.fxml"));
secPane.getChildren().add(newLoadedPane); 
}
```

Comment: You can indeed load an fxml file dynamically. If your question is any more involved than that, you'll have to edit it to add a bit more about your actual code and what you've tried that hasn't worked.

Comment: I try by this but doesn't work
@FXML Pane secPane;
public void loadFxml (ActionEvent event)  {
secPane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/application/fxml2.fxml"));
}

Comment: and what specific error are you getting when you try to run that?

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: And what's null on the specific line that went wrong? the FXMLLoader? the resolved resource?

Comment: No need to edit question to add an answer, just [select the correct answer from the available answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).  You can [accept your own answer to your question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) if you wish.

Comment: Thank you  jewelsea, but i have less than  15 REPUTATION to select my answer as an answer, do u mind if select my answer?

Comment: I'd love to Hussein but StackOverflow only permits the asker to accept an answer.  I updated your question, to give you 5 more reputation points, so almost there... :-)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I finally found this works after trying !

```
@FXML Pane secPane;
public void loadFxml (ActionEvent event)  {
  Pane newLoadedPane =  FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/application/fxml2.fxml"));
  secPane.getChildren().add(newLoadedPane);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Just replacing the field in your controller class won't change the scene graph.

`secPane` is just a reference to a node in the scene graph.

If `secPane` is just a placeholder, you could replace it in the parent's child list:

```
public void loadFxml (ActionEvent event) {
    // load new pane
    Pane newPane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/application/Login2.fxml"));

    // get children of parent of secPane (the VBox)
    List<Node> parentChildren = ((Pane)secPane.getParent()).getChildren();

    // replace the child that contained the old secPane
    parentChildren.set(parentChildren.indexOf(secPane), newPane);

    // store the new pane in the secPane field to allow replacing it the same way later
    secPane = newPane;
}
```

This assumes of course, that `getClass().getResource("/application/Login2.fxml")` yields the correct resource and does not return `null` (which happens if no resource with the given name is available)

Answer (score 1):

You can implement something like this :

```
 public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
            primaryStage.setTitle("Title");
            primaryStage.setScene(createScene(loadMainPane("path_of_your_fxml")));
            primaryStage.show();

    }

    private Pane loadMainPane(String path) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();

        Pane mainPane = (Pane) loader.load(
                getClass().getResourceAsStream(path));

        return mainPane;
    }


    private Scene createScene(Pane mainPane) {
        Scene scene = new Scene(mainPane);
      return scene;
    }
```

Then you can create a separate class call **Navigation** to store all your fxml paths:

```
public class Navigator {

private final String P1;
private final String P2;
//then you can implement getters...
public String getP1() {
    return P1;
}

public String getP2() {
    return p2;
}

private static FxmlController Controller;

    public static void loadPane(String fxml) {
    try {
        FxmlController.setPane(
                (Node) FXMLLoader.load(Navigator.class.getResource(fxml)));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public Navigator() throws IOException {
    this.P1 = "p1.fxml";
    this.P2 = "p2.fxml";}
```

Then you can load your pane in your button like below:

```
@FXML
    private void btnAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    Navigator.load(new Navigator().getP1());
    ..
```

.

Comment: The answer is not clear because `FxmlController` is not defined