# How to load scenes created in Scene Builder into JavaFX application main class?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx-2, scenebuilder

I can't find a clear example of how to write the Main class in the JavaFX application to use the fxml files created in Scene Builder, the part that loads and shows the  stage and the scene. Can someone please show me one? I have created 7 different screens and controllers for my application, but the main class has me stumped. This is a different question than just creating the fxml markup in the main class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load fxml file inside Pane?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33748127/how-to-load-fxml-file-inside-pane)

Comment: No, it is not a duplicate, thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javafx/1580/fxml-and-controllers/5125/example-fxml#t=201703071841446199167

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Main class with main method:

```
public class Main extends Application {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
          launch(args);
   }

   @Override
   public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
      String fxmlResource = "MainWindow.fxml";
      Parent panel;
      panel = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(fxmlResource));
      Scene scene = new Scene(panel);
      Stage stage = new Stage();
      stage.setScene(scene);
      stage.show();
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you this was the perfect answer to my question, I had looked everywhere and you helped me sooooo much, thank  you!